# Unit testing RX sequence where one of the streams is delayed and the other may include slow operation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

Imagine a simple processing stack where we want to ensure each incoming message has to be handled within a certain SLA. If it wasn't, we want to send a failure response to the originator. Only one response should be sent - success or failure, whichever comes first.
Modelling this seems simple.

```
public class RxTests : ReactiveTest
{
    [Test]
    public void TestSlowProcessing()
    {
        var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
        var obs = scheduler.CreateHotObservable(OnNext(100, 1), OnNext(200, 2));
        var processed = obs
        // this is the main processing which may in some cases take a long time
/*
        This code works as expected
            .SelectMany(
        val => val % 2 == 0 ? Observable.Never<int>() : Observable.Return(val)); 
*/
        // this fails under test I guess because Sleep does not "yield" to the delayed observable and the main path processing ticks first
        .Select(val => 
        {
            if (val % 2 == 0) 
            {
                // how can I waste time here and let delayed observable tick?
                scheduler.Sleep(10000); 
            }
            return val;
        });
        var delayed = obs.Delay(TimeSpan.FromTicks(1000), scheduler);
        var merged = processed.Merge(delayed).Distinct(_ => _);
        var observer = scheduler.Start(() => merged, 0, 1, 1000000);
        // We expect the second output message to come from the delayed feed.
        Assert.IsTrue(observer.Messages[1].Time == 1200);
    }
}
```

The real code uses Select as we just need to transform the incoming message using some potentially slow calculations. But I can't find a way to emulate this slowdown in a unit test. Wait, await etc. will all deadlock. Any ideas?